# jvector map of CA wants to simply link provinces to each html page

Tags: html, hyperlink, jvectormap

I'm using following CA map :

assets/jquery-jvectormap-ca-lcc-en.js

I didn't do any modification in any file.

What i want just link all provinces to their html pages whenever someone is click on any of it.

Here is the live demo page where I'm using :http://mindsharehost.com/maps/tests/reverse-projection.html

Comment: This is not really a question. What have you done; what result do you expect; and what results are you getting from it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply chris. I have html pages for all provinces and I want to link with all provinces. whenever some one click on the any province it will land on a html page.
 
What I would like to know how to make link in jvector map ... I'm not expert in javascript can anybody guide how can I make links on that map ? which file needs to be edit?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are almost done. All you need to is to redirect to the url using 
`location.href`.

```
$(function () {
    $('#map').vectorMap({
        map: 'ca_lcc_en',
        markers: markers,
        onMarkerClick: function (e, index) {
            location.href = markers[index].weburl;
        }
    });
});
```